# $.post fails with error "...is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Here is my code:

```
var jqxhr = $.post("mypage.php", {url:pageurl}, function() {
      alert("fetching...");
})
.success(function() { alert("fetch complete!"); })
.error(function() { alert("error!"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });
```

I get the alert("Fetching...") dialog box, but the rest of the code does not complete. I get the error: Error: $.post("sec_fetch_report.php", function () {alert("fetching...");}).success is not a function

I thought maybe I might be missing the jquery libs, but I have another function that calls $.post and it runs just fine. Is there a syntax error I'm missing somewhere or what?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax is broken. What you're attempting to do is call the .success property of the $.post() method, which obviously doesnt exist. It looks like you also need to be using the `$.ajax` method instead of `$.post`:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'mypage.php',
     data: { url: pageurl },
     beforeSend: function()
     {
         alert('Fetching....');
     },
     success: function()
     {
         alert('Fetch Complete');
     },
     error: function()
     {
         alert('Error');
     },
     complete: function()
     {
         alert('Complete')
     }
 });
```

Comment: His syntax is valid in version 1.6.

Comment: Sorry have to downvote, this kind of syntax is entirely valid. The jqxhr object is chainable, from v1.5 I believe.

Comment: +1 Because this syntax was invalid in some (relatively recent) jQuery version, which is not specified in the post. However, for accuracy/completeness this reply should be updated to include the jQuery version which required a method like above (or which jQuery version first allowed the proposed chainable method).

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is only supported in jQuery 1.5+ (with the introduction of deferreds). It sounds like you're using a earlier version of jQuery.  If you aren't able to upgrade, pass the success/error/complete handlers as methods of the options object (like in Tejs's example).

Comment: Deferred was introduced in jQuery 1.5 http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 1):

The jqxhr object is chainable from v1.5. Make sure you have this version or later.

Ref: [jQuery 1.5 released, now with Deferred Objects](http://thechangelog.com/post/3042787356/jquery-jquery-javascript-library)

Answer (score 0):

See examples here: [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

also, you may get error like that if you've forgotten to link jQuery library

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

> **As of jQuery 1.5**, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR,"
> returned by $.post() implements the Promise interface, giving it all
> the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise ......
>
> The Promise interface also allows jQuery's Ajax methods, including
> $.get(), to chain multiple **.done()**, **.fail()**, and **.always()** callbacks
> on a single request, and even to assign these callbacks after the
> request may have completed. If the request is already complete, the
> callback is fired immediately.

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```